# Is there any possible way to use a 32 bit library in a 64 bit c# app?

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit

I'm writing an add-in for an application which runs in 64 bit, however I need to use objects from a 32 bit library (this library only comes in 32 bit). Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you can host the 32bit library in a 32bit process then use interprocess communication to marshal data back and forth. Short answer: it isn't easy.

Comment: Do you *really* need 64-bit mode?  It is rare.  Simple fix is to just set the EXE project's Platform target to x86.

Comment: @Hans Sounds like Rick doesn't have control of the host app because he is writing an add-in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is quite easy in .NET. You just need all modules in a process to be the same bit-width.

So you simply start a child 32bit process, put all 32bit DLLs there, and use remoting features of .net to call procedures in it. Or as used to say in COM-times: Use out-of-process component server.

It will get more complicated when you need to pass a lot of data between 32bit and 64bit modules. You can setup memory-sharing, but it requires more work than normal.

Answer (score 7):

The rule here is simple, but not what you want to hear. All code in a single process has to have the same *bit-ness*. If your hosting process is 64 bit then all code in that process must be 64 bit also. Hence, if you need to run 32 bit code, you must put the 32 bit code in a separate process and use some form of IPC.